# Unable to Sort ArrayList Data using collection in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm stuck in sorting Arraylist data. I pass different ArrayList data in single arraylist with same key. I show in list view also but now I stuck in show to ascending and descending order data.

This is my Bin class

```
public class BothListClass implements Serializable {

   public List<LstItinerary> itineraryOneWay = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<LstItinerary> itineraryReturn = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<LstItinerary> getItineraryOneWay() {
       return itineraryOneWay;
   }

   public void setItineraryOneWay(List<LstItinerary> itineraryOneWay) {
       this.itineraryOneWay = itineraryOneWay;
   }

   public List<LstItinerary> getItineraryReturn() {
       return itineraryReturn;
   }

   public void setItineraryReturn(List<LstItinerary> itineraryReturn) {
       this.itineraryReturn = itineraryReturn;
   }
}
```

This is my LstItinerary class, example key

```
 public class LstItinerary implements Serializable {
     @SerializedName("ArrivalDateTime")
     @Expose
     private String arrivalDateTime;          
     @SerializedName("DepartureDateTime")
     @Expose
     private String departureDateTime;    
     @SerializedName("CustomerFare")
     @Expose
     private Float customerFare;   }
```

This is my Collection sorting method which is in Adapter class.
In this method I'm stuck how to sort, whole array list.

```
 public void sort_ascendingPrice() {
    Collections.sort(arrayList_bothClass, new Comparator<BothListClass>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(BothListClass o1, BothListClass o2) {
            Float depart1 = 0f, arrive1 = 0f, total1 = 0f, depart2 = 0f, arrive2 = 0f, total2 = 0f;

            try {
                depart1 = o1.itineraryOneWay.get(0).getCustomerFare();
                arrive1 = o1.itineraryReturn.get(0).getCustomerFare();
                
                total1 = depart1 + arrive1;

                depart2 = o2.itineraryOneWay.get(0).getCustomerFare();
                arrive2 = o2.itineraryReturn.get(0).getCustomerFare();

                total2 = depart2 + arrive2;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return total1.compareTo(total2);
        }
    });
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```